# Why I get Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        //Save files to disk
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("" + FileName));

        //Add Entry to DataBase
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnString);

        string strQuery = "INSERT INTO image([FileName],[FilePath],[AlbumName]) Values(@FN, @FP, @AN)";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strQuery);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FP", "images/" + FileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AN", txtAlbumname.Text.ToString());

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string var = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    txtAlbumname.Text = var.ToString();
}
}
```

I Have tried almost everything , but this error keeps on coming.
I have put on the brackets aswell incase of reserved words but still this error is showing

Comment: Please include the error.

Comment: try it
 INSERT INTO image(FileName,FilePath,AlbumName) Values(@FN, @FP, @AN)";

Comment: @ByteBlast I Have Already Included The Error That Syntax Error In Inser INto Statement

Comment: @KhurramAli Not Working Either

Comment: Could you try to replace the parameter names in the query by question marks (`VALUES (?, ?, ?)`)? Could be OleDbQueries have a problem replacing named parameters. Please make sure that your `AddWithValue` lines are in the required order for this to work.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Same Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OLE DB .NET` Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an `OleDbCommand` when `CommandType` is set to Text. In this case, the `question mark (?)` placeholder must be used. For example:

`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?`

Therefore, the order in which `OleDbParameter` objects are added to the `OleDbParameterCollection` must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

For Example

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
command.CommandText = 
    "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE Country = ? AND City = ?";
command.Parameters.Add(parameters);

for (int j=0; j<parameters.Length; j++)
{
    command.Parameters.Add(parameters[j]) ;
}
```

for reference ..
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

`IMAGE` is a [reserved word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx#_Toc272229040) in Access SQL so to use it as a table name you must also enclose it in square brackets:

```csharp
string strQuery = "INSERT INTO [image] ([FileName], ...
```